# li table-cell display not working

Tags: html, css, display

I have a horizontal menu built using a `<ul>` element. I'm trying to get it to evenly spread out each `<li>` across the width of the menu. Based on several answers here on SO, I used the following CSS:

```
ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

However, no matter what I try, the `<li>` elements still end up with a calculated display of `block`, with this contradictory information from the debugger (tested in FF and Chrome):

[image: contradictory display]

I didn't know what is going on here, and (more importantly) how do I get my list items to display as `table-cell`?

Comment: I think it is overridden by some other style applied to li. Could you provide the link to the page!!!

Comment: Can you show us your HTML or the function that builds your HTML ?

Comment: I'd prefer to not reveal the client, sorry. It's generated using Symfony 1.4. Where could I look to see if it's overridden? Shouldn't the debugger show what's overriding it?

Comment: You might need to add : `float:none;` to li, to avoid `display:table-cell;` to be killed ....

Answer (score 0):

In photo is showed that your style.css is really big (min.1835 lines) and because of that styles to ul could be overvritten somewhere.
To make your rule more important than existing rule, use !important keyword after rule like so:

```
ul {
  display: table!important;
  width: 100%!important;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell!important;
}
```

Comment: 1. Open Chrome
 2. Open DevTools (right click + inspect)
 3. choose table and at the right it will show you from what css line this 'display: block' come from.
 4. Go to that line and correct rule.

Comment: Look at the picture. That's exactly what I did.

Answer (score -1):

CSS has a trait called importance, it chooses which rules are the most specific and thus should override more loose rules. As you seem to use a CSS framework, your own rules don't override the framework's generic rules. Turns out that you have two options to increase the importance of your rules at `main.css`:

1. Add `!important` after your rules:

   ```
    ul li {
      display: table cell !important;
    }
   ```
2. Make your selectors more specific:

   ```
   #menu ul li.menu-list-item { ... }
   ```

Your question also looks very strange and you may be subject to a browser rendering bug, have you tried it out with other browsers?

Comment: Oh. Looks like formatting is not as obvious thing when posting on mobile, as the mobile site has no preview (and I forgot the code inside list indenting). Fix'd

Comment: Also, it's better to not style on id selectors to avoid specificity issues. If it's possible for OP, try to refactor the styles to a solution where you are not using # in your style rule. Also I wouldn't style on tags in general, but maybe that's more of an opinion :)

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. Also, in my question I mentioned that I tried in both FF and Chrome and got the same result.